# Convert manualy created DOK to CSR

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

For a machine learning task I need a sparse matrix in CSR format.
As a first step I manualy build a DOK, looking like this (based on [this](https://rushter.com/blog/scipy-sparse-matrices/) guid):

```
dok = { (0,0): 1, (0,9): 1, (5,12): 1}
#the value is always 1
#the keys representing the position in the matrix
#my DOK has around 6 million entries like these
```

I know want to format this into CSR. If I understand the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) correct, this is only possible if my input is also a sparse matrix. But my DOK is not recognised as a sparse matrix, just as a dictionary. I was also not able to cast my DOK to a "real" DOK (Following error occured):

```
TypeError: Expected rank <=2 dense array or matrix.
```

So how can I convert my DOK to a CSR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [472]: dok = { (0,0): 1, (0,9): 1, (5,12): 1}
```

Make a blank `dok` matrix:

```
In [473]: M = sparse.dok_matrix((20,20), dtype=int)                                                   
In [474]: M                                                                                           
Out[474]: 
<20x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
```

`M` is a subclass of Python dictionary.  It used to be that we could use dictionary `.update` method to efficiently add new values from a Python dictionary, but that method has been disabled (try it to see the error message).  However a backdoor has been provided:

```
In [475]: M._update(dok)                                                                              
In [476]: M                                                                                           
Out[476]: 
<20x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
```

`_update` has a cautionary comment, that values are not checked, so use with caution.

Once you have `dok` format, you can convert it to `csr` format:

```
In [477]: M1=M.tocsr()                                                                                
In [478]: M1                                                                                          
Out[478]: 
<20x20 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [479]: M1.A                                                                                        
Out[479]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ...
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
      dtype=int64)
```

If you made an error in defining your `dok`, it probably will show up in the `csr` conversion.

Another option is to iterate through your `dok` and construct the corresponding `coo` style inputs (data, rows, cols).  Those were the original style, and well worth understanding and using.